# Android: ListView doesn't populate completely

Tags: android, listview, populate

I am trying to build a RSS feed reader for my application and I have a weird problem. To implement this feed I use a ListView that I populate from an ArrayList I customised.

I know that the ArrayList is full with all the fields I want to display (I print all of them in my Logcat), but when I run the app, not all the cells in my ListView fill with the information they are supposed to, the major part of them display TextView. It seems to be quite random, but the one that always works correctly is the first element. The other ones some times do.

And another strange thing is that the OnItemClickListener works perfectly, even I am unable to see the information in my elements.

Thank you very much in advanced.

I attach my getView code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    AdapterWrapper wrapper;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.itemrow, null);
        wrapper = new AdapterWrapper(v, cont);
        v.setTag(wrapper);
    } else {
        wrapper = (AdapterWrapper) convertView.getTag();
        RssItem o = this.getItem(position);
        if (o != null)
            wrapper.populateFrom(o);
        parent.refreshDrawableState();
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "customized" an ArrayList?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant I extended an ArrayAdapter

Comment: And I didn't post any code, because I don't know where is the error, and posting all the classes didn't seem to be a good option.

Comment: I got it to work, I had a { that wasn't supposed to be after the else word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you aren't handling the recycled view case properly in `getView`.

When you check to see that `convertView != null`, you still need to actually *populate the information* in your convertView. The actual view hierarchy will be there, but the information will be from an old, recycled view associated with a different row.

For more specific information, please post your `getView` code.

**Edit** - I think you need to call `wrapper.populateFrom(o)` whether or not you have a `convertView`. Try moving that part outside of the if statement:

```
 if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = li.inflate(R.layout.itemrow, null);
    wrapper = new AdapterWrapper(v, cont);
    v.setTag(wrapper);
 } else {
    wrapper = (AdapterWrapper) convertView.getTag();
 }
 RssItem o = this.getItem(position);
 if (o != null)
    wrapper.populateFrom(o);
 parent.refreshDrawableState(); // not sure what this is doing
```

Comment: I got my error, I think the most stupid I could've made, a { that wasn't supposed to go there.

Comment: you should always use curly braces like I posted above, otherwise it is easy to make mistakes like that.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I realized, when I was reviewing the code I posted. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, I had a { that wasn't supposed to be after the

> else

word, so the code is finally:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    AdapterWrapper wrapper;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.itemrow, null);
        wrapper = new AdapterWrapper(v, cont);
        v.setTag(wrapper);
    } else
        wrapper = (AdapterWrapper) convertView.getTag();

    RssItem o = this.getItem(position);
    if (o != null)
        wrapper.populateFrom(o);
    parent.refreshDrawableState();

    return v;
}
```